# Spring MVC Java multithreading: perform an SQL statement in the background

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, spring-mvc, background

I'm fairly new to Java multithreading. So I was hoping someone with experience with this subject matter could give me an example that they've used successfully before.

My Scenario : 
I have a Spring MVC web app. A controller in the web app gets called through Ajax and returns a json object. Between the entering the controller and the return, I'd like to perform an SQL statement in the background. Meaning that the JSON return should happen regardless of whether the SQL has completed(or generated an exception).

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

```
@RequestMapping("/persist")
public @ResponseBody MyClass persist(HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request) {

   MyClass obj = new MyClass();
   obj.setTitle("This is just a test");

   // Want to make into a background process
   MyDAO mine = new MyDAO();
   mine.performSQL();        

   return obj;    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Spring 3.1+, take a look at the @Async annotation.  It's a nice simple method of managing and abstracting a ThreadPool.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this with Java 1.5 onwards

```
private ExecutorService executorService; // Initialize

@RequestMapping("/persist")
public @ResponseBody MyClass persist(HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request) {

   MyClass obj = new MyClass();
   obj.setTitle("This is just a test");

   // Want to make into a background process
   executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
          MyDAO mine = new MyDAO();
          mine.performSQL(); 
       }
   });          

   return obj;    
}
```